# I can't send data in my spring boot using multipartFile?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I can't send data to the spring boot application using react with axios. I need to send FormatData so inside it will have JSON and an image to be send to the backend. I have created the method in the backend and the error tells that it doesn't accept Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported, but in the inspect element it sends it as a"multipart/form-data". I tried using Postman and it sends successfully the data to the database but when I use the front end I can't do it.
Here's my method in backend:

```
@PostMapping("/meals")
public ResponseEntity<String> createMeal( MultipartFile [] file, @RequestPart("meal") Meal meal, @RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) {    

Meal savedMeal = authService.saveMeal(meal, imageFile);
    if (savedMeal != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Meal created successfully.");
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error creating the meal.");

    }
}

 const [mealData, setMealData] = React.useState({
        name: '',
        calories: 0,
        protein:0,
        fat:0,
        description: '',
        image: null, // State to hold the selected image file
      });
 

 function handleImage(e){
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    setMealData({...mealData,image});
  }
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setMealData({ ...mealData, [name]: value });
  }


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const meal = {
        name: mealData.name,
        description: mealData.description,
        protein: mealData.protein,
        fat: mealData.fat,
        calories: mealData.calories,
      };

      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("meal", JSON.stringify(meal));
      formData.append("image", mealData.image);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(meal));
      console.log(mealData.image);

      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/meals", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Set the content type to multipart/form-data
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this way many times, and I don't see any difference.

So without the full error and code its a beat hard to understand the problem.
But you could use a few approaches to try to understand the problem.

1. Remove the first param (`MultipartFile [] file`)
2. Verify that you are importing the correct library (`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`)
3. Try to isolate the problem, by send only one param (the file)
4. Try to set the max file size in `application.yaml` or send a small image
5. Disable any filter or interceptor

```
@PostMapping("/meals")
public ResponseEntity<String> createMeal(@RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile) {    
  
    InputStream stream = imageFile.getInputStream(); // For debug
    Meal savedMeal = authService.saveMeal(null, imageFile);
    if (savedMeal != null) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("Meal created successfully.");
    } else {
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error creating the meal.");
    }
}
```

And in the same in the UI, use only the basic:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const meal = {
        name: mealData.name,
        description: mealData.description,
        protein: mealData.protein,
        fat: mealData.fat,
        calories: mealData.calories,
      };

      const formData = new FormData();

      //formData.append("meal", JSON.stringify(meal));
      formData.append("image", mealData.image);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(meal));
      console.log(mealData.image);

      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/meals", formData, {
        headers: {
          //"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Set the content type to multipart/form-data
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Good luck